# tclError while trying to save text

Tags: python, tkinter

I've been trying build a text editor with tkinter and python, and wrote this code for saving text:

```
    def saveEdit(event):
    global active
    if active == True:
        active = False
        with open(root.fileName, 'w') as editedFile:
            editedFile.write(textWidget.get(1.0, 2.0))
editor.bind('<Destroy>',saveEdit)
```

however, this gives an error that I don't understand:

```
 Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\merijn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/merijn/PycharmProjects/infoprojectP3/venv/Scripts/infoprojectP3.py", line 83, in saveEdit
    editedFile.write(textWidget.get(1.0, 2.0))
  File "C:\Users\merijn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3706, in get
    return self.tk.call(self._w, 'get', index1, index2)
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!toplevel.!text"
```

any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: That almost always means the text widget has been destroyed

Comment: yeah that makes sense, because I'm trying to make it so if you destroy the text widget it saves the text automatically, any tips on doing this without getting the error?

Comment: get the data before destroying the widget.